# Single timer or multiple timers in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, timer, socket.io

**Hi there! I am developing Auction in Node Js (Express framework,socket.io). Can you advice me what is the better way to use single timer for every product or multiple timers for each product?**

For example (code is minimal):

once started...

```
for(active products) {
    timer[timer_id] = setInterval(..
       sec--; 
       ....
    )
}
```

or
every second...

```
timer = setInterval(..
   for(only active products)
   {
      sec--;
   }
)
```

Both programming codes are working now. But I want to know which way is better or are there any other way to do it?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Use as few a number of timers as you can cleanly write the code with.